# Can you add borders around padding?

Tags: python, bokeh

Can't find anything about this in the documentation and I've taken a guess at a few variable names... sadly that didn't work.

Is it possible to add a boarder around the outside of the plot. I would have thought it would have been similar to the Plot glyph that has the attribute 'outline_line_color' - unfortunately, for figure these changes the line surrounding the direct plot, not the padding.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bokeh draws on an HTML Canvas. This wrapped in a few tight divs but generally speaking, Bokeh is only responsible for what it is on the canvas. If you want to control external things outside the plot, Bokeh provides APIs for embedding plots and other objects. Then you can use standard CSS to style your page around/outside the plot however you like. It would be an enormous wasted effort for Bokeh to try and duplicate all of HTML/CSS styling options in a non-standard way.

If you are embedding standalone (i.e. non-bokeh server) plots, then [`bokeh.embed.components`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components) is a good option. Otherwise if you are embedding a Bokeh server application you would want to use [`server_document`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#server-data) (or an `<iframe>`).

Edit: So, just to be clear, there is no *API* to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your response - for maximum customisation would you recommend I learn HTML/CSS?

Comment: If you want to customize things *around* Bokeh plots then yes I think a very cursory understanding of HTML/CSS will be helpful (it is often helpful in many other situations I have found)

Comment: Thanks for advice :)